# How to build a simple $http post test script using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm just beginning to understand Angularjs and planning to build an app. I'm really a PHP programmer and have little background in javascript. Angularjs was introduced to me by a friend. I was warned that I have to also learn its Jasmine/karma testing before the functionality of the app gets bigger. So here goes, for now I have a $http post which submits an email and a password which if success return a token. Basically if success will redirect the user to the user/profile page

Controller code:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $location, Api, localStorageService, Security) {
 $scope.loginUser = function () {
    Api.authenticatePlayer({
        email    : $scope.main.email,
        password : $scope.main.password
    }).then(function (result){
        //success
        $location.path('/user/profile');
    }, function(result) {
        //error also this will catch error 400, 401, and 500
        console.log(result.data);
    });
 };
}
```

And here is my testscript:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp.services'),
    module("myApp.controllers")
});

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $location, Api, localStorageService, $httpBackend, Security) {
    this.$location = $location;
    this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
    this.redirect = spyOn($location, 'path');

    $controller("MainCtrl", {
        $scope : this.scope,
        $location : $location,
        localStorageService : localStorageService,
        Security : Security
    });

}));

describe("successfully logging in", function () {
    it("should redirect you to /user/profile", function() {
        //arrange
        var postData = {
            email : this.scope.main.email,
            password : this.scope.main.password
        }
        this.$httpBackend.expectPOST('login', postData).respond(200);
        //act
        this.scope.loginUser();
        this.$httpBackend.flush();
        //assert
        expect(this.redirect).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/user/profile');
    });
});
```

Here is my service.js code:

```
return {

  /**
   * Authenticate player
   * @param   object postData      Email and password of the user
   * @return object
   */
  authenticatePlayer: function(postData) {
    return $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : api + 'auth/player',
      data    : postData,
      headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    });
  }
 }
```

The testscript failed :(. 
Here is the error:

```
Chrome 24.0 (Linux) controller: MainCtrl successfully logging in should redirect you to /user/profile FAILED
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://domain.com/auth/player
Expected POST login
```

Can anyone please help. So sorry for the trouble though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is because `Api.authenticatePlayer` is calling to a different path than what you are expecting.

Your test should have this instead:

```
this.$httpBackend.expectPOST('http://domain.com/auth/player', postData).respond(200);
```

Basically, in your test, `$httpBackend` is a mock of the code that would call your API.  You get to say "When my code calls this URL, respond with *_*".  In this code, you are saying that you expect the post to happen and to return an empty response of 200.  You could replace "200" with the json payload that you want to pretend that the server responded with.

Comment: i updated my question. please take a look above. I've added the authenticatePlayer function. the page where my login reside is in my /home and its partials is sign_in.html.

Comment: oh, okay I understand a bit now. So if I want to test the response when failed I'll just change the respond(400/401/500) then assert the error result. Am i right?

Comment: Yes.  Completely.  That line is all about setting up test responses.  You can mock out anything the server might throw at you.